# Jenkins Inegration with TestNG.(when running from jenkins it's not invoking browser)

Tags: maven, jenkins, integration, testng

My project contains (Webdriver,Maven3.05,jenkins) when I run maven command "mvn test" , test will trigger and browser will be invoked, the same set when i had configured using jenkins it will run the tests but browser will not be invoked.Please help me where iam going wrong.(I had installed testng plugin for jenkins all necessary configurations are taken care).

Comment: Could you please provide some details of your jenkins installation? Is jenkins OS user able to start a browser (env variables, display availability, filesystem permissions)?

Comment: Jenkins Version:1.514, testng plugin 1.1 tomcat 7 ,jdk 1.6.0_18 if you need more info plz let me know..

Comment: The Operating system that I am using is windows-7, and i had given all permissions to my firefox folder, still no luck

Comment: I rather meant: 1. Is it a *nix box? 2. is jenkins launched as a service?My point is that when you execute mvn, it's your OS user with all the necessary paths, environment variables and permissions; when jenkins runs the same, it may be different user/

Comment: When u say tests are running..do they pass or all fail ..with what error, if they fail?  The tests would run on the mc where Jenkins is runnin..unless until u hv configured a grid? Is ur Jenkins hosted on ur local mc?

Comment: @patrungel,As i said Iam using Windows-7, but i don't know how to check under which credentials jenkins is running.

Comment: @niharika_neo : they are all pass,I can see the same results when i run using maven and jenkins, but in case of jenkins firefox browser is not opening up.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting jenkins using the command line:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

Usually in Windows not all the services are allowed to use the interface

Hope helps!